# How to retrieve the table row where a td has an id with name mailaddress?

Tags: jquery

I am working with datatables and included a delete action, for that i need to have the tr selected with jquery. But i do not know how to get the tr of the row where a td exists with name mailaddress.

Here is my table

```
        <table id="table_id" class="display">
        <thead>
            <th>Property</th>
            <th>Value</th>      
            <th></th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <button id="create-property">Create new property</button>

            <tr >
                <td>mailAddress_object</td>
                <td id="mailAddress_object" >Message from SendALL 2.5</td>      
                <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="deleteRow_1" name="mailAddress_object"></span></td>                     
            </tr>       

            <tr >
                <td>mjmj</td>
                <td id="mjmj" >xcvxcv</td>      
                <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="deleteRow_2" name="mjmj"></span></td>                       
            </tr>       

            <tr >
                <td>olol</td>
                <td id="olol" >kjkkjk</td>      
                <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="deleteRow_3" name="olol"></span></td>                       
            </tr>       

            <tr >
                <td>plsUrl</td>
                <td id="plsUrl" >http://komm2.srs-management.de</td>        
                <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="deleteRow_4" name="plsUrl"></span></td>                     
            </tr>       

            <tr >
                <td>scPwd</td>
                <td id="scPwd" >sysadm</td>     
                <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="deleteRow_5" name="scPwd"></span></td>                      
            </tr>       

            <tr >
                <td>smtp</td>
                <td id="smtp" >YOUR_MAILSERVER</td>     
                <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="deleteRow_6" name="smtp"></span></td>                       
            </tr>       

            <tr >
                <td>test</td>
                <td id="test" >test3</td>       
                <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="deleteRow_7" name="test"></span></td>                       
            </tr>       

            <tr >
                <td>useEncryption</td>
                <td id="useEncryption" >false</td>      
                <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="deleteRow_8" name="useEncryption"></span></td>                      
            </tr>       

        </tbody>    
        </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get it with parent

```
$("#mailaddress").parent("tr");
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't very efficient, but this should work:

```
$("input[name='mailAddress_object']:first").parents('tr:first')
```

There are usually better ways to do this so that the code won't have to do as much work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("tr:has(td[name='mailAddress_object'])")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td[name=mailaddress]')
```

will give you td with name=mailaddress and then you can get the parent for tr

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you mean a `td` with an id of `mailAddress_object`, which is what your code shows:

```
var $tr = $('#mailAddress_object').closest('tr');
```